# How to add in case validation in a text based game

Tags: python

I'm using pycharm to write the code

I'm making a text based game for a school project and have pretty much finished. However, my instructor recommended I add case validation for the input for better UX. I can't for the life of me figure it out.

She's asking that i make it so the user can input the direction with different letter cases.

as of right now only west, east, south, north are valid inputs, all lowercase. How can I can add case validation?

[dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukkuA.png)

[movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJMdL.png)

I tried changing the dictionary to 'west' or 'West' and adding 'West' to the list of directions. That didn't even make West a valid input. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Convert the user input to lowercase immediately.  That way you don't care  if they typed "west" or "West".  `direction = input("Which way?").lower().strip()`

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

if you want the easy way, go with the .lower() function, it turns every uppercase work into a lowercase word.

however, you could also try to implement it on your own by making an array of lowercase letters and an array of uppercase letter, and then replacing every upper by it's lower counterpart